# ubuntu 12.04.2 - evolution 3.2.3: Is there a Logfile?

Tags: evolution

my evo does not send mail. Servers are correct. Is there a log file to see what evolution is doing ? A few days ago, everything still was fine.

Is there any other logfile, I could check ?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about any log file, but there are debug settings you can enable when starting Evolution from the command line. Find the full description [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evolution/Debugging). In your case, you most likely want to debug SMTP, which currently doesn't have its own separate debug setting. Accodring to the linked manual, here's how you could debug that:

```
CAMEL_DEBUG=all evolution >& evo_debug.log
```

This would first enable full debug in evolution (`CAMEL_DEBUG=all`), and then start Evolution itself (`evolution`) -- while redirecting all the debug output to a file (`>& evo_debug.log`). This way you've got all information stored for later reference in the file `evo_debug.log`, which will be created in the directory where you executed above statement from. Alternatively, you can of course specify an absolute location for the log:

```
CAMEL_DEBUG=all evolution >& ~/evo_debug.log
```

would store the log file directly in your home directory, for example.

Comment: If you are using Exchange: `EWS_DEBUG=2 evolution >& logfile`